# Binding to a property name via DependencyProperty string

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I've created a `UserControl` with an `ItemContext` `DependencyProperty`. This property contains the name of the property of my `DataContext` object the Control's text property should bind to.

I cannot figure out how to do this in XAML. I tried several steps, I'm quite near but couldn't find it.

Something like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type me:UserControl}}, Path=ItemContext}" />
```

But here the contents of "ItemContext" is bound directly to the Text Property which I don't want. The contents of "ItemContext" let's say "Property1" is the name of the property in my DataContext I'd like to bind to.

In code it works like this:

```
this.txtValue0.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding(this.ItemContext) { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
```

Does someone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: not sure if this has anything to do with it, but you don't set the Mode in your XAML code.

Comment: @Kshitij: it's implicit in the Xaml.  I'm not sure it's actually relevant in the code, either.

Comment: I thought the default mode was OneWay. Guess you learn something new everyday :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as though what you're trying to pass an external value into the `Path` property of a `Binding` object.  That is, if `ItemContext`'s value is "Blob", you want to bind to `DataContext.Blob` (not display the value "Blob").

That's easy to do in code, because you can reference the value directly (you pass `this.ItemContext` to your binding as a one-time value).  In markup, however, you can't do this.  Instead, you're trying to *bind* a value to the `Path` of the `Binding`, but you can't (because it's not a DependencyProperty).

I'd suggest that a much easier solution would be to create a different property on your UserControl: instead of passing in "the name of the thing you want to bind to," why not just pass in the value of the thing?

I'm imagining that your current code looks like this:

```
<u:MyControl DataContext="{Binding SomeObject}" ItemContext="MyPropertyName" />
```

... and instead you should make it look like this:

```
<u:MyControl DataContext="{Binding SomeObject}" ItemValue="{Binding MyPropertyName}" />
```

... so the value is resolved externally of the control.  Within the control, you can use @dowhilefor's solution to bind to the value.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks four your answer. You are pretty right with your statement "That's easy to do in code, because you can reference the value directly". I tried to find a way to do this in XAML - but now I'll end up and let it in the code. Passing the value is not possible because inside my UserControl there are 4 controls and each has a different DataContext.

Comment: I'd suggest you change your solution as I suggested.  Doing it in the code is pretty horrible if you can avoid it!  Is there a reason you're binding in the property name instead of the value?

Comment: the reason is I have 4 different DataContexts (4 instances of the same object) and my 4 controls should bind to the same property in these 4 instances - I hope you can understand my explanation

Comment: That should still work if you just changed DataContext and had a regular binding instead of what you have currently :)

Comment: I see another possibility for this: I can create a DependencyProperty for each of the 4 DataContexts I'll pass into my UserControl and then I can use a regular binding.

Comment: Why can't you just use a regular binding with the DataContext?  Creating four properties sounds like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it correctly. You want to use a dependency property from your usercontrol code behind, in your user control xaml? 
Just give in xaml your user control a name `x:Name="myUserControl"` and in your Binding write `{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=MyDependencyProperty}.` Thats at least how i do it, unless someone has a better idea of that strange limitation.

Comment: I think that `ItemContext` contains the name of the property he wants to bind to, not the value.  We'll see when the OP replies tho :]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

Xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.DetailDataControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Name="root">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemContext,ElementName=root}" Height="30" Width="100"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code Behind

```
 public partial class DetailDataControl : UserControl
    {
        public DetailDataControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemContextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ItemContext", typeof(string), typeof(DetailDataControl), new PropertyMetadata("default value"));

        public string ItemContext
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ItemContextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemContextProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

instead fo binding with relative source i have give name to user control. idon't some how relative source will not work as expected with self binding...

Comment: I don't believe this solves the problem the OP is having.  I think that `ItemContext` contains the *name* of the property he wants to bind to, not the value.

Comment: @Dan you're right. I'm not trying to bind to the property directly - instead I want to bind the property's value.